# wp_add_inline_script vs wordpress fetch api

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, react

Inorder to pass some data from PHP to the javascript files, we can use either **wp_add_inline_script** or **fetch api**. Is there any condition, where each one of them is preferred over the other ? I have used both but feeling some confusion.

Suppose, if I have a plugin page, which shows a list of settings saved in option table. The page is rendered using React. So need to get the value for the settings from database in React files. So in this case, I can call **get_option** and pass them to my react (or javascript) file using **wp_add_inline_script** or make use of **fetch api** in the react **useEffect** hook. But I think **wp_add_inline_script** is better so I can reduce the fetch calls and may be the performance.

So depending on **security, performance and coding standards**, is there any cases that should be considered while choosing between this two ? In my case, both of them are used to pass data from PHP to React.

Comment: Your question is interesting, but it is also subjective/opinion-based.. So I could only say, if the data would only be needed at certain point in your code or on the page, *maybe* fetch is preferred (i.e. don't load until it's needed). But that's just my opinion and doesn't necessarily mean I'd choose doing so.

Comment: @SallyCJ I agree that it is opinion based. But I am not able to differentiate between the two. I need the data to render the page. I mean, the value of the input fields will be the data I get through **wp_add_inline_script** or **fetch api**.

Comment: Yes I understand, but there isn't much I can say. In the past though, I also had a project where the plugin page was mostly AJAX-based (using jQuery back then), and I chose to load the data via AJAX, because - 1) The page source was large, and 2) I wanted the data be available only within the context of my code as opposed to globally within the page, i.e. the `window` object. You might want to try doing it that way, but I'm not saying it's a better option.

Comment: @SallyCJ I understand, the data I need consists of many database operations. That's why I was a bit confused. Also I am starting the project in react and Fetch API was recommended everywhere. Is there any security issues while making the data available globally i.e, the window object?

Comment: That was just my preference back then, it wasn't because of any security issues. Advanced users could change the data even if they were "private", anyway. Therefore, as long as you properly sanitize and validate data prior to making any DB operations on the server side, then it's really up to you to use whichever option best suited in your case. And if it helps, if 9 out of 10 (or maybe 60%) people recommended fetch/AJAX, then maybe you should use it. After all, you can always *try* (it's just about loading the data, right?), and see if it worked well or that the other should instead be used.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks for the valuable input. If it was an answer other than the comment, I would have upvoted it. I have tried those both approach and I really prefer the wp_add_inline_script.

Comment: If this was a question like "how to use wp_add_inline_script" or maybe "why my wp_add_inline_script code is not working", I would have probably posted an answer. You know what I mean, right? :) Anyway, all the best and happy coding!